# Getting Error "error CS1525: Invalid expression term '>'" in Unity 2022

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In unity getting error "error CS1525: Invalid expression term '>'" and in Visual Studio the error is:

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error CS8400
Feature 'relational pattern' is not available in C# 8.0.
Please use language version 9.0 or greater.
```

here is the line of the error:

```
if (sr is { Length: > 0 })
```

and here is the full if condition:

```
if (layeredBlock == null || !layeredBlock.AnyLayersExist())
            {
                if (sr is { Length: > 0 })
                {
                    LevelManager.Instance.DestroySpriteEvent(sr[0].sprite, transform.position, this, null);
                }
            }
```

Can anyone help solving this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (sr is { Length: > 0 })` is a feature of c# 9 and later versions.

If you need to check if `sr` is not empty please use one of the following checks:

- `if (sr.Count > 0)`
- `if (sr.Any())`

Another thing you can resolve it, is to bump `.NET` version

Comment: How can I bump .NET version?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not familiar with Unity, but in .NET projects, you should find `.csproj` file and view the current version